# Eigen3's autovectorization and pass between functions

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Can Eigen3 vectorize the division when the a class A passes columns of an Eigen::Array member, another class B takes the column, and then do the division with B's Eigen::Array?

Example:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
class A_interface {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void div_by(const T& rhs);
    const auto col(const int col_id) const;
};
enum A_implementation { test };
template <A_implementation A_t> class A;

template <>
class A<test> : public A_interface{
public:
    A(const int n_rows, const int n_cols) 
            : _n_rows(n_rows), _n_cols(n_cols), 
              _data(n_rows, n_cols) {}
    const auto col(const int col_id) const { 
        return _data.col(col_id); 
    }
    template <typename T>
    void div_by(const T& rhs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _n_cols; ++i) {
            _data.col(i) /= rhs.col(i);
        }
    }
private:
    const int _n_rows;
    const int _n_cols; 
    Eigen::ArrayXXf _data;
    template <A_implementation A_t> friend class A;
};
int main() {
    A<test> a(10,2);
    A<test> b(10,2);
    a.div_by(b);
}
```

I want to do this because not all implementation of A uses an Eigen::Array.

In this case is the double loop in `div_by` method vectorized by Eigen3 or the compiler?

Comment: Passing eigen matrix should use templates as in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html I guess auto is fine though (or not?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `div_by` will be vectorized if both arrays are stored column-wise (the default in Eigen).  But why are you doing a loop on the columns? What about `_data/=rhs` ? Why are you storing `_n_rows,n_cols`? The info is already in `_data`.

Comment: loop on columns with openmp for loop. I was deciding between Eigen and std::vector and only do array operations, and didn't realize the Eigen array already store those. (I hope getting the dimension of the array doesn't involve any indirection or calculation if I use compiler optimization ...) Thanks for the answer.